# Performant way to find maximum value across partitions

Tags: cassandra

I have a table with a **clustering** column, and I want to find the maximum value (across partitions). My intuition is, that this should be quick if there are only a handful of partitions, because on each partition, it only has to read the last row. But it turns out, that it is not:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  customer_id bigint,
  nr bigint,
  val text,
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, nr)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (nr ASC);


select max(nr) from example;

   ...
   Executing seq scan across 1 sstables ...
```

With enough data, this gets very slow.

If I only need the maximum from one partition, I can do:

```
select nr from example
where customer_id=3
order by nr desc
limit 1;
```

And that doesn't require a seq scan. However, this approach cannot be used across partitions.

- Why is the seq scan necessary?
- Is there any alternative solution that can be used across partitions? (I tried using an index on the clustering column, but it doesn't make any difference)

Comment: I don't understand: find the max will always require to read from all the partitions, collect the results and apply max(), so that's the slowest thing I can imagine...

Comment: @Cedric: Yes, it needs to read from all partitions. But I only have a handful of partitions (I tried it with two partitions). So in each partition it should find the max (should be very quick, because it's a clustering column), and then it  just needs to take the maximum of those few values.

Comment: I see. Are you sure that max (or min) are implemented in this smart way, or a just collecting all results (as mean or std would have to do) ?

Comment: It seems, that it doesn't perform a seq scan, if and only if I restrict the customer_id (`WHERE customer_id=...` or even `WHERE customer_id IN (...)`). I guess, this could lead to some workaround, but I assume, that the IN clause will get too large, as the number of customers grows.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that apparently if you specify the partition key then only one value of the clustering column is read, while if not specifying the partition key, all partitions are read (of course), but that inside all the partitions all the clustering values are collected?

Comment: I'm not 100% confident in reading cqlsh's traces, but it does look exactly like that to me.

Comment: Interesting. Should you file a Jira? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/cassandra